# Is it possible to printf the memory address of the first element of an array in C?

Tags: c, printf

Is it possible to `printf` the memory address of the first element of an array in C?

The compiler reports an error when I try to:

```
printf("i%/n", @array[0])
```

Where I've declared `array[] = {23, 56, 78}`.

Comment: In C, @ does not denote an array. Read a basic book :)

Comment: check a reference for [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: @Fiddling why not perl ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("i%/n", @array[0])
```

should be

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)&array[0]);
```

Use the format specifier `p` to print address

Answer (score 5):

Did you try:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)array);
```

?

Comment: Technically, you also need to convert `array` to `void*` but leaving out the cast is fine on all but some weird platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `%p` formatting specifier. Use `&` instead of `@` to take an address, although this is redundant: `&foo[0]` is equal to `foo` except when an operand to `sizeof`. Technically, you also need to cast the array pointer to `void*` unless it's a pointer to character (`char*`) in which case the cast isn't needed:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)array);
```

Comment: Would you expand on "... unless it's a pointer to character `(char*)`..."?  The C11 spec says "The argument shall be a pointer to `void`."

Comment: @chux See ISO 9899:2011 §6.5.2.2 ¶6 #2: *If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the types of
the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases: (...) both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a character type or `void`.*

Comment: @chux Sorry, wrong quote. The right one is of course §7.16.1.2 ¶2 #2 which reads similarly: *If there is no actual next argument, or if
type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases: (...) one type is pointer to `void` and the other is a pointer to a character type.*

Comment: §7.16.1.2 specifies `va_arg()` and we do not _know_ `printf()` uses  `va_arg()`.   §6.5.2.2 does look closer to the issue.  IAC, doubt real machines would have any trouble.  Might make a good SO post?

Comment: @chux §6.5.2.2 considers unprototyped functions (which printf isn't), so it doesn't apply. §7.16.1.2 considers the only standard way to retrieve variable arguments, it's unlikely that the committee intended `printf()` to behave more restrictive than any function with variable arguments you could define in standard C.

Comment: §6.5.2.2 6 discuss "...If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (`, ...`) ..." just like `printf(const char * format, ...);`

Comment: @chux But that's the previous sentence. The sentence I refer to only applies to functions without a prototype.

Comment: Hmmmm.  I see your point.  Agree - 99.9%.  IMO, it would seem that "If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype,.... except... —  ... — ..." _should_ also apply to the `...` arguments of `printf()`.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @chux It was a pleasure to me.